# Get "pure" controller/method name in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

Consider this code:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::controller('articles', 'ArticlesController');
});
```

When the user visits `http://localhost/admin/articles/edit` Laravel is able to parse the Uri and execute `ArticleController::anyEdit`. When the url is `http://localhost/admin/articles` then `ArticleController::getIndex` will be chosen.

Is there any *good* method the relevant tokens (admin/,articles,edit and admin/,articles,index) without re-implementing all the logic?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Just manually define each route - its much easier. Read this article: http://philsturgeon.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I don't intend to.

Comment: so what do you *want* to do then? what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to implement smart (overridable) defaults as seen in the earliest release of CakePHP.

Comment: If you want to change the default behavior of routes, then you should just define them individually. There is not any other clean way around it.